# Entering folder based on name in python

Tags: python

In my code, I'm able to search through a directory for a file with a specific name.  How could I edit the code so that it first searches for folders with names ending with the word "output".  In the below code, when I tried to include the commented out line, the whole thing refused to run.  Any help on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated

```
def test():
    file_paths = []
    filenames = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/Bashe/Desktop/121210 p2/'):
        for file in files:
                #if re.match("output", file):
                    if re.match("Results",file):
                        file_paths.append(root)
                        filenames.append(file)
    return file_paths, filenames
```

Comment: Try to use `os.path.dirname(file).endswith('output')`.

Comment: @1st1: your expression is always false. `file` is relative to `root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search files that are in a folder with name ending with the word "output":

```
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if not dirpath.endswith('output'):
       continue # look in the next folder
    # search files
    for file in files: ...
```

If you don't want even to visit any directories that are not ending with `"output"`:

```
if not rootdir.endswith('output'):
    return # do not visit it at all
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    assert dirpath.endswith('output')
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d.endswith('output')] # edit inplace
    # search files
    for file in files: ...
```